# Firefox 49 dev tools where is "Store as global variable" stored?

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

In dev tools when I right click a variable from the console and choose "Store as global variable," what variable is this stored to? It's not in `$p` or `$0`. It does not output anything to the console that might indicate where it is stored.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tempN` is the right syntax, but not everything can be stored as a global variable.

Try this:

- type `document.body` in the console prompt and submit
- the output should show something like `<body>`
- right click on it and select "store as global variable"
- this will add `temp0` to the console prompt, and you can then press enter to see its value, or use it later for something else.

If you do this once again, then `temp1` will be defined, etc.

If you right-click on something that can't be stored, the "store as global variable" menu item should normally be grayed out, but it looks like sometimes it isn't, which is causing the problem you described.

This is a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1318315) that should be fixed, simply, not something that you're doing wrong.

Comment: Why would a chunk of a json response be something that couldn't be stored?

Comment: Also, this doesn't do anything. I get the same result; nothing is output to the console and temp0 is undefined

Comment: You're right, the tool ought to be able to to store a JSON response. It probably just never was implemented.
Also, if the 4 simple steps I gave don't do anything for you, then you most probably have encountered a bug that I don't have here. Would you like to file an issue here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools%3A%20Console

Answer (score 0):

While stopped, you could open the console and run:

`window.globalvar = JSON.error.trace` or whatever the object is you want to be available later.

Comment: Are you sure that it creates a variable with the name `JSON`?

Comment: it definitely doesn't. JSON is a built in javascript object. The JSON in the screenshot is referring to the JSON response of an ajax request.

Comment: If there is "JSON" or any other local variable, it should make it global for later.